# Need help to set up a physics question/answer/think environment

Tags: lists, environments

I am writing a physics study guide for my students. For working out examples, I created a new environment that can contain up to three parts: the question, the answer, and something to think about afterwards. The parts should be separated by a thin rule.

I need some help to tweak it more to my liking. Things I'd like to fix:

- I may only have a think about, in which case I don't want the rule.
- To save me from myself, an example environment must contain a question with an answer (and optionally a think), or only a think. I don't want to have an example with only a question or only an answer.

Naturally, I welcome better ways of accomplishing what I want.

My working example is

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{framed}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!8}

\newenvironment{example}{
  \newcommand{\sep}{\hfill\rule[0.25em]{0.5\linewidth}{.7pt}\hfill\null\newline}

  \newcommand{\question}{{\bfseries Question: }}
  \newcommand{\answer}{\sep{\bfseries Answer: }}
  \newcommand{\think}{\sep{\bfseries Think about: }}
  \begin{shaded}\begin{quote}
}{\end{quote}\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}

I don't want the rule below if there's only a think about:
\begin{example}
  \think Blah, blah, blah.
\end{example}

Where's the answer? I don't want questions without answers.
\begin{example}
  \question When it first starts raining, will it be large or small
  raindrops that hit the ground first?
\end{example}

What was the question?
\begin{example}
  \answer Raindrops vary in size from 0.5~\si{mm} in diameter to
  4~\si{mm}. Larger raindrops will split into smaller drops.

  Blah, blah, blah.
\end{example}

My ideal for examples with question/answer/think parts:
\begin{example}
  \question When it first starts raining, will it be large or small
  raindrops that hit the ground first?

  \answer Raindrops vary in size from 0.5~\si{mm} in diameter to
  4~\si{mm}. Larger raindrops will split into smaller drops.

  Raindrops reach terminal velocity $v_T$ almost immediately after
  they start falling. This means that the drag force (pointing up)
  becomes equal but opposite to the raindrop weight (pointing
  down). Finding the terminal velocity will determine what sized
  raindrops hit the ground first when the rain storm begins.

  Blah, blah, blah ...

  \think Give a physics explanation for why falling hailstones are
  more dangerous than falling raindrops.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image: My MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not programmer but this do what you need

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{framed,tikz}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!8}

\newif\ifque\quefalse
\newif\ifans\ansfalse

\newcommand{\sep}{\hfill\rule[0.25em]{0.5\linewidth}{.7pt}\hfill\null\newline}

\newcommand{\question}{\quetrue{\bfseries Question: }}
\newcommand{\answer}{\ifque\anstrue\sep{\bfseries Answer: }\else\errmessage{You need question}\fi}
\newcommand{\think}{\ifans\sep\fi{\bfseries Think about: }}

\newenvironment{example}{%
  \begin{shaded}\begin{quote}}{%
  \ifque\ifans\else\errmessage{You need answer}\fi\fi%
\end{quote}\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}


I don't want the rule below if there's only a think about:
\begin{example}
  \think Blah, blah, blah.
\end{example}

Where's the answer? I don't want questions without answers.
\begin{example}
  \question When it first starts raining, will it be large or small
  raindrops that hit the ground first?
\end{example}

What was the question?
\begin{example}
  \answer Raindrops vary in size from 0.5~\si{mm} in diameter to
  4~\si{mm}. Larger raindrops will split into smaller drops.

  Blah, blah, blah.
\end{example}

My ideal for examples with question/answer/think parts:
\begin{example}
  \question When it first starts raining, will it be large or small
  raindrops that hit the ground first?

  \answer Raindrops vary in size from 0.5~\si{mm} in diameter to
  4~\si{mm}. Larger raindrops will split into smaller drops.

  Raindrops reach terminal velocity $v_T$ almost immediately after
  they start falling. This means that the drag force (pointing up)
  becomes equal but opposite to the raindrop weight (pointing
  down). Finding the terminal velocity will determine what sized
  raindrops hit the ground first when the rain storm begins.

  Blah, blah, blah ...

  \think Give a physics explanation for why falling hailstones are
  more dangerous than falling raindrops.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following snippet by combining ideas from several TeX stackexchange posts. It seems to give me what I want. Basically a description environment with the special commands \question, \answer, and \think. I can still use the usual \item command if I want to, so I can use a regular list inside my example environment.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{framed}

%% \newenvironment{example}{
%%   \newcommand{\sep}{\hfill\rule[0.25em]{0.5\linewidth}{.7pt}\hfill\null\newline}

%%   \newcommand{\question}{{\bfseries Question: }}
%%   \newcommand{\answer}{\sep{\bfseries Answer: }}
%%   \newcommand{\think}{\sep{\bfseries Think about: }}
%%   \begin{shaded}\begin{quote}
%% }{\end{quote}\end{shaded}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\myitem\@item
\patchcmd{\myitem}
         {\addvspace\itemsep}
         {\par\kern\dimexpr.7\itemsep-.7\parskip-.7\baselineskip\relax%
          \hfill\rule{0.5\linewidth}{.7pt}\hfill\null%
          \par\kern\dimexpr.3\itemsep-.3\parskip-.3\baselineskip\relax}
         {}{}%
\makeatother

\newtoggle{question}
\newtoggle{answer}
\newtoggle{think}

\newenvironment{example}{
  \togglefalse{question}
  \togglefalse{answer}
  \togglefalse{think}

  \newcommand{\question}{\toggletrue{question}\myitem[\bfseries Question]}
  \newcommand{\answer}{\toggletrue{answer}\myitem[\bfseries Answer]}
  \newcommand{\think}{\toggletrue{think}\myitem[\bfseries Think about]}

  \colorlet{shadecolor}{orange!8}
  \begin{shaded}\begin{description}
}{
  \ifboolexpr{togl {question} and togl {answer} or togl {think}}
             {}
             {\errmessage{You need both question AND answer items, or a think-about item}}
  \end{description}\end{shaded}
}



\begin{document}

Must have both question and answer parts, or a think-about part:
\begin{example}
  \think Ok, let's think about this.
\end{example}

Full example:
\begin{example}
  \question When it first starts raining, will it be large or small
  raindrops that hit the ground first?

  \answer Raindrops vary in size from 0.5~\si{mm} in diameter to
  4~\si{mm}. Larger raindrops will split into smaller drops.

  Raindrops reach terminal velocity $v_T$ almost immediately after
  they start falling. This means that the drag force (pointing up)
  becomes equal but opposite to the raindrop weight (pointing
  down). Finding the terminal velocity will determine what sized
  raindrops hit the ground first when the rain storm begins.

  Blah, blah, blah ...

  \think Give a physics explanation for why falling hailstones are
  more dangerous than falling raindrops.

\item[A regular description] can also be used.

  The usual list environments are also ok to include:
  \begin{itemize}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
  \end{itemize}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image: Better MWE]